# Auto correct / auto spell-check and auto correct without asking user

Tags: javascript, autocorrect

I want to develop a system for a shipping company. If I type the region as "COLMBO" or "COLUMBU" or COLOMBU or "COLAMBU" or anything which may spell the same (exact word is COLOMBO), I need to auto correct it through the system, Web language, specially javascript related help is required to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

I would make this as a suggestion for user, so that user should confirm it for correction to happen. If a word contains correction suggestion then display small button near that word, once user press it then display possible options, when user click option then make the correction.
To make it possible, I think custom edit box control is required that convert separate words into separate html elements (spans or divs). It can be built from html div and non-visible input element (it would have focus and keyboard handlers).
When user press space then new word has to be checked on server, just send AJAX request with new word and display correction suggestions if any.